# How to escape quotation ' in object filter Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable which filters for certain text field inputs, but when I try to input **'** **quotation** my app crash with this output:

> uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to
>   parse the format string "word LIKE ''*'"'
>   *** First throw call stack:

here is my code:

```
func getEnglishWords(_ Phrase: String) -> [DictionaryResult] {

    let Words = realm.objects(Word.self).filter("word LIKE '\(Phrase)*'").sorted(byKeyPath: "word", ascending: true)

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter on word beginning with a single-quote? As in `'test` would match, but `test'` would not? So `Phrase = "'"`?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, Filter words starting with single-quote

Comment: Try: `let Phrase = "\\'"`

Comment: The phrase is a dynamic variable, I edited the answer code section.

Comment: I assumed it was dynamic... My suggestion is to hard-code it that way, and see if you get the results you want or if it is still unable to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try filtering using an NSPredicate object, and also I think BEGINSWITH would be easier to use than LIKE in this case. See the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) for examples and links to additional documentation and cheatsheets for NSPredicate use.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "word BEGINSWITH %@", Phrase)
let Words = realm.objects(Word.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "word", ascending: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let escapedString = "You can \"escape\" like this"

print(escapedString) // prints You can "escape" like this
```

Comment: I want to include ' in my search results, so this isn't the answer.

Comment: Do you mean simple quote? You don't have to escape it in a String made with double quotes. Maybe the `Phrase` has a \ ?